# super.input1 = input.nextInt();

Tags: java, inheritance, java.util.scanner, super

Anybody can please tell me what is the use of super keyword here ?
I am trying to code for addition operation using inheritance in which three classes are there, where variables are declared in one class and actual code for operation is in another class and and main class is there.

```
class Oper extends Variables {
    void op() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any two numbers: ");
        super.input1 = input.nextInt();
        super.input2 = input.nextInt();
        result = input1 + input2;
        System.out.println("Result = " + result);
    }
}

class Variables {
    int input1, input2, result;
}

class Addition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Oper obj = new Oper();
        obj.op();
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code of both classes please

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: @RahulGour update the question with these snippets and remove the comments please

Comment: @RahulGour `super.` here is redundant. You can get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

[super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) following the javadocs says that:

> If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can
>   invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword super. You
>   can also use super to refer to a hidden field (although hiding fields
>   is discouraged).

In your example super is referencing to the properties of the parent `class Variable`. You can omit It, as the child class do not have properties with the same name. If you would have the same variables name at `Variable` class and at `Oper` class then you would have to use it to differentiate.

and about `input.nextInt()`:

in your case input is `System.in` so It is reading from system input, by default It is the console input. 
`nextInt()` is reading the characters and converting them to an int type ([more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt())).

> Reads four input bytes and returns an int value

Comment: "super" is not require here?

Comment: can you please tell the working of this "input.nextInt()"?

Comment: Hi, `super` is keyword which refers to class parent. In this case class `Oper` is child of class `Variables`, so if you make instance of `Oper` it also inherits the class fields, methods, or whatever from parent class (`Variables`). 
Over there `Oper` instance will have fields from `Variables`, `    int input1, input2, result;
`, so with `super.input1` you are referring to the `Oper` class field `input1`, which is inherited from `Variables`... 
Same with methods, etc.
refer to docs eg. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: super can be omitted in this example as some of the people have said.